# excel and pc stuck freeze and bugged when openning files writen with r

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, openxlsx

i am writing excel files with an R script that read existing file run some formulas on it and then adding some columns to the original file and writing it as new file, but when i am opening the files in excel , i sometime get freezes and excel stuck , or even without opening excel my computer freeze a bit (for example file explorer not responsive)

i tried using write.csv , openxlsx and the xlsx libarry all bugged my computer a bit

EDIT: my files are pretty small something like 800X20 without any formulas only tables of numbers and letters they take about 100 kb, but i tried some functions for big files like write.xlsx2 which didn't help , i just have no idea what can impact on it im adding columns like that :

```
orgData["codes"]<-codes
time=rep(NA,length(orgData$codes))
time[1]=totalTime
orgData["totalTime"]<-time
```

right now i am using write.xslx from the openxslsx library like this :

```
orgData=orgData[,c("c1","c2",.....)]
orgData=analayze(orgData,name)
name=(paste(gsub('.{3}$',"",name),"xlsx",sep=""))
write.xlsx(orgData,file = paste("Out.",name),row.names = FALSE )
```

Comment: There's no helpful information in this question. If you try to load a file with 1M rows in a single sheet, Excel will take some time to load it. If that sheet contains a lot of formulas that get recalculated automatically, it will take even more. If the computer isn't fast enough, or its RAM isn't enough, it will go even slower

Comment: I use `openxlsx` with functions `loadWorkbook`, `writeData` and `saveWorkbook` and I have no problems. On the other hand, I agree with previous comment

Comment: hi thanks for the quick response i edited it a bit , my excel files are really simple with only numbers and letters no macros or anything , and the only place i interact with anything outside my code is when i write and read the files, important to mention maybe that the freezing dont happen every time only after using it for sometime, so im really at lost of what could cause it  @PanagiotisKanavos